# Login page loading as partial and not full page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'm having a problem in my Angular app. I have the index page which contains a sidebar and a topbar. With ng-view I then load the contents based on what is clicked on the sidebar.

However, this page requires authentication and as such I have a login page to which I want to redirect when the user is not authenticated. The problem is the html is loading as a partial with the sidebar and topbar aswell, when I want it to be a different page.

Here's my code:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html'
                        //controller: 'mainController'
                        //controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    ;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Any additional code that is required to help please say so!
Thank you!

Comment: What did you mean by 'html is loading as a partial' ? I developed a similar application like this. May be I can help you.

Comment: I have and index that has ng-view which depending on the route loads a partial/template through templateUrl. I have the /login route and, kind of as expected, it loads into the "partial spot" the login page, when I want it to be a completely different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is user seeing content which he should not see without login in then add the authentication in resolve function inside when block. If you put the login page inside the view with sidebar and topbar user will always see those things. create a separate page for login if you don't want user to see topbar and sidebar, then route to home on login success.

Comment: That is part of the problem. It IS a different page and that's how I want want it to show. However, I don't know how to make it a different page and then redirect to home on login success. Can you help me on that please?

Comment: In angular.run() route to login page by default. On login store username and encrypted password in the cookies or storage. On login success route to home from js. On every route add 'resolve' function to check the user is allowed to use that page or not. Use UI-router for easy routing. `$state.go('home')`. Check Ui-router documentation for more details and examples

Comment: How do I route to login? Because I'm using $location.path( "/login" ); and it just loads the login in the partial spot

Comment: It's loading inside the ngView inside that html page. You are loading the index.html with top n side bar then inside the view you are opening the login page. remove top and side bar from index and make it a seperate file. Index should only have a ngView.